# Communication between variable number of Docker containers

Tags: python, docker

I have 3 different types of images (A,B,C). Python script on my Docker host starts X containers from image A, Y containers from image B and Z containers from image C. All instances have their names assigned (A0, A1, A2,... B0, B1...) and they need to send and receive messages to each other according to predefined scheme (not relevant for the question). X, Y and Z can be changed before running the cluster, so each run can have different amount of each containers running for each of the images.

What is the best possible way to make all containers aware of the names and/or IP addresses of the other containers that they need to communicate to, including docker host?

Some of the ways that I found include:

- Using Docker API to send GET request to host and parse the reply to get all running containers (docker ps -a)
- Using environment variables, set by script which runs all containers

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at things like serf and consul: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. This could do the job, but if I want to run Consul on Docker host my containers need to know the address of the host, so they can register their services. How can I make containers aware of the address of the Docker host (and my Consul server at the same time)?

Comment: I think you need to look up how consul works (and etcd).

Comment: if you know in advance how many containers from A, from B, from C... you will run, you can put all this in a file, passed to the `docker run` command starting each container, see `--env-file=[]              Read in a line delimited file of environment variables` from the run syntax http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run